# Java compare CSVs in Junit tests - if failure, give specific line(s) of failure

Tags: java, csv, junit

I've got some Junit tests that compare large blocks of JSON using a framework called [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit).

When there is a failure in the test, it's typically just a few lines in a 1000+ line JSON. The JsonUnit framework will give me the exact sections of the JSON that are failing like this:

> ```
>  but: JSON documents are different:
> ```
>
> Different value found in node "sent[0].acknowledgedTime", expected
> <"09:56:22.216213"> but was .
>
> Different value found in node "sent[0].reopeningNumber", expected
> <"RA"> but was <"RU">.
>
> Different value found in node "sent[0].sentTime", expected
> <"09:55:42.776926"> but was <"09:55:53.901321">.
>
> Different value found in node "sent[0].value", expected <1.0E+8> but
> was <2.0E+10>.
>
> Different value found in node "sent[0].volume", expected <10000> but
> was <30000>.

I also have large 1000+ line CSVs that I want to compare in a Junit test.  If there is a failure, I want it to give me the exact line(s) that failed. Is there a framework out there for CSVs like the JsonUnit?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply read the CSV document to a list of Strings and then use [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/)

```
assertThat(currentCsvAsLines)
    .contains("some, example, line");
```